# GWT: Expose the service implementation class as web service

Tags: web-services, gwt, web

Problem scenario is: I am writing a Google Gadget. Data presented in the gadget will come from my deployed GWT app. I am planing to call the web service from Java script  to show the required data.

I need to know how I can expose the Service implementation class like GreetingServiceImpl(generated by default as sample in Eclipse GWT project) as web service.

I did tried to to expose the logic using approach suggested here(http://igorshare.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/building-gwt-web-clients-part-2-how-to-expose-rest-full-jax-rs-service-with-jersey-on-tomcat-server/).

But rather than creating the dynamic web project, I created the Google web project in Eclipse. And I am getting the 404 exception.

Any suggestions why I am getting 404 error?

Regards, 
Vikram

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Retrieving JSON Data](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON)